# Kinvey DataStore Does Not Save

Tags: ios, xcode, kinvey

I am tying to understand the Kinvey docs by writing a simple app to save an object "book" in a collection "Book"

Unfortunately I receive the following error

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
```

My code is as follows

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Kinvey
import SVProgressHUD

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
lazy var fileStore: FileStore = {
    return FileStore.getInstance()
}()


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    Kinvey.sharedClient.initialize(
    appKey: "kid_rJngK8I_x",
    appSecret: "6439a2ee96ef412083f10108666f6004"
    )


    if let _ = Kinvey.sharedClient.activeUser {
        //do nothing
    } else {
        SVProgressHUD.show()

        User.exists(username: "test") { exists, error in
            if exists {
                User.login(username: "test", password: "test") { user, error in
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    if let _ = user {
                        //do nothing
                    } else {
                        //do something!
                    }
                }
            } else {
                User.signup(username: "test", password: "test") { user, error in
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    if let _ = user {
                        //do nothing
                    } else {
                        //do something!
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true

}
```

Book.swift

```
import Foundation
import Kinvey

class Book: Entity {
dynamic var title: String?
dynamic var authorName: String?

override class func collectionName() -> String {
    //return the name of the backend collection corresponding to this entity
    return "Book"
}
//Map properties in your backend collection to the members of this entity
override func propertyMapping(_ map: Map) {
    //This maps the "_id", "_kmd" and "_acl" properties
    super.propertyMapping(map)
    //Each property in your entity should be mapped using the following scheme:
    //<member variable> <- ("<backend property>", map["<backend property>"])
    title <- ("title", map["title"])
    authorName <- ("authorName", map["author"])
}
}
```

ViewController

```
import UIKit
import Kinvey

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let dataStore = DataStore<Book>.collection()

    let book = Book()

    book.title = "Steal This Book"
    book.authorName = "Abbey Hoffman"

    print("Abbey Hoffman")



        dataStore.save(book) { book, error in
            if let book = book {
                //succeed
                print("Book: \(book)")
            } else {
                //fail
            }// close else
        }  //closesave block



    }


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

When I comment out the following from ViewController.swift my code runs without issue

```
dataStore.save(book) { book, error in
            if let book = book {
                //succeed
                print("Book: \(book)")
            } else {
                //fail
            }// close else
        }  //closesave block
```

A new user is generated on the backed but nothing is added to the book collection

Below is a screenshot of my debugger window[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bryan,

See if it can be solved with a Clean & Build (or perhaps relaunch Xcode). You might also consider deleting the relevant folders from ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData.

Provide me with the screenshot of the error that you are getting. If you could provide me with sample project where you are seeing the error that would be great.

Also, what version of the SDK you are using?

Thanks,
Pranav
Kinvey Support

Comment: Clean and Build and restart of XCode didn't work unfortunately.  I edited my original post to include a screenshot of my debugger window.

Comment: I am using the newest SDK compatable with iOS 10 , swift 3, xcode 8